# What transliterates € -> EU and ™ -> (tm)?

Tags: transliteration, mojibake

On the streaming service Kanopy, I have noticed that some descriptions have strange looking text.

[Screenshot from Kanopy showing mojibake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtpfW.jpg)

Screenshot shows:

`BogieaEU(tm)s`

and

`HepburnaEU(tm)s`

With a little effort, my theory is this:

The text started as

`Bogie’s`

Using `’` (U+2019) as the apostrophe.

This was saved as UTF-8 as the bytes `[0xe2 0x80 0x99]`

That sequence of bytes was then treated as Windows-1252 or some other encoding, so that the output was `â€™`

So far, this is standard mojibake and I am not asking about that.

Some process then converted `â€™` into `aEU(tm)`.

That is:

```
â -> a
€ -> EU
™ -> (tm)
```

Looks like some kind of transliteration, converting Unicode into an ASCII approximation.

I am wondering about the precise piece of software that is doing this conversion. I can't find it!

For example, iconv is a very popular library for doing transliteration.

But you can see on the main page here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

that iconv converts `€` into `EUR`, not `EU`.

So iconv is not doing this transliteration.

unidecode is another popular library.

But unidecode also converts `€` into `EUR`

```
>>> unidecode('\u00e2\u20ac\u2122')
'aEUR(tm)'
>>>
```

Is it possible to find the precise piece of software that transliterates `€` -> `EU` and `™` -> `(tm)` ?